# How to validate against multiple fields and display a unique error?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to validate a control against multiple fields.  And I want to display an error indicating which field(s) caused validation to fail.

Run the following code.  Change the first value to a high number (E.G. 5) and validation will pass.  Change the first value to a low number (2) and validation will fail.

In the case of "2" there should be 2 errors:  model3, model4 because those models are higher values than 2.  Similarly for all other fields.

The validation works fine.  I'm having trouble displaying the correct error messages based on the particular validation rule that failed.

Note, any field changes must re-fire validation just like it does now.  You should run this snippet in full page view.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) { 
  $scope.model = {number: "1"};
  $scope.model2 = {number: "2"};
  $scope.model3 = {number: "3"};
  $scope.model4 = {number: "4"};
});

app.directive('theGreatest', function(){
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function($scope, $element, $attr, ngModel) {
            var compareCollection;

            // watch the attribute to get the date we need to compare against
            $attr.$observe('theGreatest', function (val) {
                console.log('compareCollection set to: ', val);
                compareCollection = JSON.parse(val);
                ngModel.$validate();
            });

            ngModel.$validators.theGreatest = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
                 console.log('validating...', modelValue);
                 console.log('compareDate: ', compareCollection);
                    
                var pass = true;
                _.map(compareCollection, function(compare){
                  console.log('comparing value: ', compare);
                  if(modelValue < compare){
                    pass = false; 
                  }
                });
        
                console.log('validation pass', pass);
                return pass;
            };
        }
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.11/angular.min.js"></script>
<section ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<div>first: <input type="text" ng-model="model.number" the-greatest="{{[model2.number, model3.number, model4.number]}}" />
  (change me to a high number)
  </div>
<div>second: <input ng-model="model2.number" type="text" /></div>
<div>third: <input ng-model="model3.number" type="text" /></div>
<div>fourth: <input ng-model="model4.number" type="text" /></div>
  <div>validation passed if you see a value here: {{model.number}}</div>
  <div>The following errors are not implemented correctly.  The intention is to show what I am want to accomplish</div>
  <div ng-if="!model.number">ERROR: first is less than model 2</div>
  <div ng-if="!model.number">ERROR: first is less than model 3</div>
  <div ng-if="!model.number">ERROR: first is less than model 4</div>
  
  <div ng-if="!model.number">ERROR: first is required</div>
</section>
```

Comment: I got idea for it, but it wont be generic, 
send another array of flags in directive and while you validating check it fails 1st time, 2nd time or 3rd time and set that flag to false. it will show that msg and other wont be visible

Comment: @WasifKhan - Not a bad idea. Feel free to post an answer demoing it. I'll see if the community comes up with something more generic, but that may just be enough.

Comment: @WasifKhan - With your idea can we specify an index of the error?  In this case, Index 0 can tell me to show "Error: first is less than model2".  Will that work?

Comment: Yes,you can do it like that. but what if you need to show two errors, first is less than model2. first is less than model3!!

Comment: @WasifKhan - I was thinking of returning an array of indexes somehow.  In that case `[0,1]`

Comment: Yes that is the exact comment I said first, array of flag, like boolean is best. and set it to true and false in your validation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149627/discussion-between-wasif-khan-and-p-brian-mackey).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send ErrorFlags array into directive and while you are validating mark those flags as false when validation fails.

### HTML:

```
<section ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div>first: <input type="text" ng-model="model.number" the-greatest="{{[model2.number, model3.number, model4.number]}}" error-flags="errorFlags" />
    (change me to a high number)
    </div>
    <div>second: <input ng-model="model2.number" type="text" /></div>
    <div>third: <input ng-model="model3.number" type="text" /></div>
    <div>fourth: <input ng-model="model4.number" type="text" /></div>
    <div>validation passed if you see a value here: {{model.number}}</div>
    <div>The following errors are not implemented correctly.  The intention is to show what I want to accomplish</div>
    <div ng-if="!errorFlags[0]">ERROR: first is less than model 2</div>
    <div ng-if="!errorFlags[1]">ERROR: first is less than model 3</div>
    <div ng-if="!errorFlags[2]">ERROR: first is less than model 4</div>

    <div ng-if="!model.number">ERROR: first is required</div>
</section>
```

### AngularJS Code:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) { 
  $scope.model = {number: "1"};
  $scope.model2 = {number: "2"};
  $scope.model3 = {number: "3"};
  $scope.model4 = {number: "4"};
  $scope.errorFlags = [true, true , true];
});

app.directive('theGreatest', function(){
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
          errorFlags:"="
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            var compareCollection;

            // watch the attribute to get the date we need to compare against
            attrs.$observe('theGreatest', function (val) {
                console.log('compareCollection set to: ', val);
                compareCollection = JSON.parse(val);
                ngModel.$validate();
            });

            ngModel.$validators.theGreatest = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
                 console.log('validating...', modelValue);
                 console.log('compareDate: ', compareCollection);
              scope.errorFlags = [true, true, true];
                    console.log("Before Validation Flags", scope.errorFlags);
                var pass = true;
              var loopVariable = 0;
                _.map(compareCollection, function(compare){
                  console.log('comparing value: ', compare);
                  if(modelValue < compare){
                    pass = false;
                    scope.errorFlags[loopVariable] = false;
                  }
                  loopVariable++;
                });
              console.log("after Validation Flags", scope.errorFlags);
                console.log('validation pass', pass);
                return pass;
            };
        }
    };
});
```