# How can I use isolated scope with a component and a directive?

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive, angular-components

The goal here is to let `MainCtrl` know when there is an error(s) found in the directive.  The error must be displayed here:

`<div ng-if="errors[0]">Error 1: {{errors[0]}}</div>`

How can I get isolated scope with a directive inside a component?  The following application works if you uncomment the 2 lines mentioned below.  As it is, I get error:

[Multiple Directive Resource Contention](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/multidir?p0=panel&p1=&p2=testDirective&p3=%20(module:%20app)&p4=new%2Fisolated%20scope&p5=%3Cpanel%20test-directive%3D%22%22%20text%3D%22%7B%7Btext%7D%7D%22%20errors%3D%22errors%22%3E)

I can read the causes.  I need to know how to fix this while still allowing the directive to have isolated scope.  I may have 3-4 of these directives on a page and each one needs it's own unique of `errors` that is also available to the parent.

[(working case example on codepen)](https://codepen.io/smacky311/pen/WEeoQe?editors=1010)

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.errors = [false, false];
  $scope.text = "bobby";
});
 
app.directive('testDirective', function(){
  return {
   restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      errors: '=',
      text: '@'
   },
    link: function($scope, $element, $attr, ngModel) {
      console.log('link fired');
      console.log('errors: ', $scope.errors);
      console.log('scope.text', $scope.text);

      $attr.$observe('text', function (val) {
        if($scope.text === 'bobby'){
          $scope.errors[0] = true;
        }else{
          $scope.errors[0] = false;
        }
      });
    },
   template: '<p>text: {{ text }} </p>'
     + '<p>errors: {{errors}}</p>'
     + '<p><input type="text" ng-model="errors" /></p>'
  };
});


app.component('panel', {
  bindings: {
  },
  template: [
    '<div>',
    '</div>'
  ].join(''),
  controller: function() {
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.11/angular.min.js"></script>
<section ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <h3>Parent Scope</h3>
  <p>errors: {{errors}}</p>
  <input type="text" ng-model="text"></div>
  <div ng-if="errors[0]">Error 1: {{errors[0]}}</div>
  <div ng-if="errors[1]">Error 2: {{errors[1]}}</div>

<!--  UNCOMMENT THE FOLLOWING 2 LINES AND THIS APP WILL WORK
  <h3>Directive by itself</h3>
  <div test-directive text="{{text}}" errors="errors"><div>
  -->
    
  <h3>Directive in component</h3>
  <panel test-directive text="{{text}}" errors="errors"></panel>
  
</section>
```

Comment: The AngularJS framework doesn't allow two isolate scopes on the same element. Also two directives with both with templates won't work. How do you expect the two templates to resolve? What do you want the user to see? What are you trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: See [Error: $compile:multidir for Component Directive with Attribute Directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45196150/error-compilemultidir-for-component-directive-with-attribute-directive/45204883#45204883) for one fix.

Comment: @georgeawg - What I am trying to accomplish is given in the first line of the question.  You can get rid of the template in the directive, it's just a bad example.  All the directive needs to do is validation on change.

Comment: In reality, I have 4 date components on a controller.  Each uses a directive to validate the selected date.  And the controller needs to know if there is an error and what kind.  A date controls validation can depend on the selected date in a separate date component  @georgeawg

Comment: For example,  delete date needs to be after start date and also after otherSelectedDate.  The error needs to indicate which controls caused the error.  So control 4 may have 0-4 separate errors

Comment: Are you doing the [Custom Validation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#custom-validation) with the [ngModelController API](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController)? Seems like what you want can be accomplished with that.

Comment: @georgeawg - This is the related question asked prior that does that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45194560/how-to-validate-against-multiple-fields-and-display-a-unique-error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching, I noticed Angular only returns bool from `$validators` (as opposed to `object`).  At this point I decided my approach was wrong.  I decided to create a unique `$valiators` for each unique error message.  Then use `ng-message` for the output.

In order to work with multiple components on the same page, I also have to check the `ngModel.$error` as part of validation.  [This blog](https://www.yearofmoo.com/2014/05/how-to-use-ngmessages-in-angularjs.html) covers the basic approach.